# Reading a value from csv file dash python

Tags: python, python-3.x, geopandas, plotly-dash

I have value map_geo_location in csv file like `(123.456,789.1234)` , How can I get the value in dash to add it as the values for the attributes `lan` and `lat` geo scattered dash in python?

Comment: I want to use it for displaying map location based on the  value (123.456,789.1234), so i want it as lan=123.456 , lat=789.1234

Comment: see if the answer posted below helps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

list.txt:

```
(123.456,789.1234)
(763.426,659.9834)
(873.566,789.6734)
(773.766,239.234)
(343.776,889.1344)
(873.766,679.1344)
```

and then:

```
logFile = "list.txt"
with open(logFile) as f:
    content = f.readlines()

# you may also want to remove empty lines
content = [l.strip() for l in content if l.strip()]

lat = []
long = []

for line in content:
    lat.append(line.rpartition(',')[2].strip(")"))
    long.append(line.rpartition(',')[0].strip("("))


print("Latitude List: {}".format(lat))
print("Longitude List: {}".format(long))
```

OUTPUT:

```
Latitude List: ['789.1234', '659.9834', '789.6734', '239.234', '889.1344', '679.1344']
Longitude List: ['123.456', '763.426', '873.566', '773.766', '343.776', '873.766']
```